# Dynamic instantiation of unknown amount and names of parameter attributes in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a growing robust application, with many variables.   As I create a variable at a higher level, that needs to be passed down the lineage, it takes a lot of time to keep writing code to manage that the variable gets passed down.   If I know which variables I always want to pass down (not necessarily back up, so these aren't necessarily global, just uni-directional), what method can I write in the initialize function to accomplish this, without having to manage the naming conventions?

This code would likely be most useful at each level, so as I create parameters at the parent level to be passed to the child View, each child View would just iterate through the parameters and attach them with their passed in name.

So if there is a parent View `Fruits`, and it creates all child views `Oranges`, and `Oranges` creates all `Navels` and `Valencias`, in the `initialize(options)` of `Oranges`, `Navels`, and `Valencias`, there would be a function that iterates through each `options` attribute, and sets itself to the View.  If `options` has 5 number attributes created in the parent View, it would look like `this.1 = options.1;`, `this.2 = options.2;`, `this.3 = options.3;`, `this.4 = options.4;`, and `this.5 = options.5;` at each of the levels.

This would allow me to manage the names only in the parent view, although I would have to know the name since it would not be in the file of each child, but I am ok with this, as the attributes are unique throughout the hierarchy, and any unique names could be manipulated prior to passing them to the Child view.

I was trying something like this for a middle Child view:

```
define([ … ], function( … ){
  return Backbone.View.extend({
    events : { … },
    // options = { 1:thing1, 2: thing2, a: itA, b: itB }
    initialize: function(options){
      if (options) {
        for (var key in options) {
          'this.' + key = options[key];  //Here is the line that would accomplish this
        }
      } else { //…defaults… }
    },
    render: function(){
      // If i needed to manipulate them, I could accomplish this here
      var params = {
         1: this.thing1,
         2: this.thing2,
         a: this.itA,
         b: this.itB
      };
      new childView(params);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: qoute it like this `"1": `

Comment: Bracket notation: `this[key] = options[key];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @go-oleg I used Bracket notation: this[key] = options[key];

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do all the manipulation in the view. I feel that is a bad practice , as technically speaking `View` should be completely **dumb** of the data or `Model`. If not the model and the view will be tightly coupled.

Instead create a model that turns the data into the format you require.

There is `parse` function inside the model which will be called before `initialize`.

So all the calculations can be performed there making the view ignorant..

```
define([ … ], function( … ){
   return Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {

        },
        parse: function() {
             // Do your changes here
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: Their will be several different views of the same model (not sure if I should make them each their own type), and each view can change between the types, so the information of the other views should be available to each view.

Comment: If the views in question have the same functionality, you can maintain a single model for all these.. I mean a new Model of same instance for each view

Comment: I am only beginning to understand this convention.  Thanks for your help.